# scroll view of android not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, scroll, uiscrollview

I've already made a scrolling view with buttons as the individual grids. However, once I changed the backgrounds of the buttons to images, the view just stopped scrolling. One of the warning it gave was "Too much work on main thread". I was wondering could that be the problem to why the scrolling doesn't work anymore? Thanks a lot!

Update: i found out that when I used smaller image sizes, the error disappeared! The issue was that all the images inserted were really big, as a result the entire program does not run smoothly and the scroll view just stops working.

Comment: Share you code will help solve issue fast.

Comment: share your layout & activity pls

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem and using a smaller images as background solves my problem. Try to replace your images to smaller ones and see it works for you.